# Edit/Update button functionality

Tags: html, angularjs, button, angular-ui-grid

I am working on the page where i enter the values into a textbox and on clicking save button they get saved in a UI grid. The table even contains the edit button. On clicking edit button the field in the table should be editable and onclicking update button the changes should be saved and cannot be modified.
I have tried out something but I am not getting proper output for the update button.
Code is added on jsfiddle..Here  is the link https://jsfiddle.net/a8n1d01q/

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Header Details</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link href="font.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="header.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="headerCtrl">
        <h2 style="text-align: center"><b>Header Details</b></h2>

        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <!--<div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center">


                                <a>Add the Headers </a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>-->

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <h1>
                                &nbsp; <b>Enter the Header:</b>&nbsp;
                                <input type="text" name="Header" ng-model="header"><br>
                            </h1>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <p>

                    </p>

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <h1>
                                &nbsp;  <b>Status:</b>&nbsp;
                                <select name="status" id="status" ng-model="status">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">(Select the status)</option>
                                    <option value="Active">Active</option>
                                    <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>

                                </select>
                            </h1>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="pull-right">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="Save()">Save</button>

                        <button type="clear" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>

                    </div>






                </div>
            </div>




            <table class="table table-bordered" ;style="width:40%;margin-left:400px">
                <tr>
                    <th>Header</th>
                    <th>Status</th>

                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in headerData.Result">
                    <td><input type="text" input-disabled="editableInput" value={{data.Header}} ></td>
                    <td><input type="text" input-disabled="editableInput" value={{data.Status}} ></td>
                    <td>
                        <!--<button class="editbtn">edit</button>-->

                        <button ng-click="editableInput = !editableInput">
                            <span ng-show="editableInput">UPDATE</span>
                            <span ng-show="!editableInput">EDIT</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="editbtn">delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>


            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular JS code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('headerCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.headerData = {};
    $scope.headerData.Result = [];
    $scope.Save = function () {
        $scope.headerData.Result.push({
            "Header": $scope.header,
            "Status": $scope.status

        });

    };

    $scope.clear = function() {
        console.log($scope.header);
        console.log($scope.status);
        $scope.header = "";
        $scope.status = "";


    };

    $scope.editableInput = false;
    app.directive("inputDisabled", function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.inputDisabled, function (val) {
                if (val)
                    element.removeAttr("disabled");
                else
                    element.attr("disabled", "disabled");
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you add it on jsfiddle?

Comment: added...please check https://jsfiddle.net/a8n1d01q/